# Avoid fixed height issue related to Bootstrap Navbar. (Mega Menu)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to avoid fixed height of bootstrap columns. I do have a Custom Mega Menu in my project where we show all our Nav bar entries. This one is a dynamically created code so it will be difficult to change the logic of the Mega menu creation so I am looking for some Css solution to fix this issue.

My code in high level look like.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-3">... contents </div>
<div class="col-xl-3">... contents </div>
<div class="col-xl-3">... contents </div>
<div class="col-xl-3">... contents </div>
<div class="col-xl-3">... contents </div>
<div class="col-xl-3">... contents </div>
</div>
```

Since this one is a dynamic item we can expect n number of `col-xl-3`

The issue is I am getting some extra space in between columns. ( taking the max size item's size in each row)

[image]

As you can see in the image attached, The yellow color marked area I am trying to avoid.

I have tried to use `d-block` with `float-left` to the child elements.

Then I am getting display something like below.

[image]

Here also I am getting extra space in some places. Is there any way to get out of this issues?

What I am looking for is to move  sections 5 to below 1 st section and 6 one to below 2 nd section etc .And remove the extra space between top and bottom columns
(the yellow highlighted space in the image)

I am adding a testing sample below here.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css">
</head>
<div class="container-outer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12 navtop">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

                    <div id="navbarContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-md-column">

                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto second-ul">

                            <ul class="navbar-nav treemenu">
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
                                    <a class="nav-link mnn-nav-link channelclass" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"
                                       role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        MENU
                                        <i class="fa fa-down"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu w-100 ddn" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <div class="row d-block">
                                            <div class="col-xl-3 float-left">
                                                <p data-id="ACCT" class="submenu-title mnn-sdaaaent-nav-click">
                                                    1
                                                    <i class="sub-up-down fa-up fa"></i>
                                                </p>

                                                <ul class="list-unstyled  ACCT ">

                                                    <li>
                                                        <a class="mnn-nav-sub-click" data-id="IPASSBOOKACCT">
                                                            seffwew
                                                            <i class="fa fa-down"></i>
                                                        </a>

                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled  seffwewACCT mnn-nav-ul-sub" style="display: none;">

                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/asASasAS/GI/Index/#=PTR_KTYU#">General Information</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/asASasAS/AccountSummary/Index/#=PTR_KTYU#">sefscsdsd Summary</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/asASasAS/Transaction/Index/#=PTR_KTYU#">Transaction</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>

                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="/asASasAS/DeferredIncome/AdminIndex">sfdsfsds Income</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xl-3 float-left">
                                                <p data-id="TAX" class="submenu-title mnn-sdaaaent-nav-click">
                                                    2
                                                    <i class="sub-up-down fa-up fa"></i>
                                                </p>

                                                <ul class="list-unstyled  TAX ">

                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="/Communications/Tax/TaxForms/2019/Forms">2019 sdfdsfsfsdfs Forms</a>
                                                        <sup class="newtext">NEW</sup>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2019/2019POFManual.pdf">2019 POF Manual</a>
                                                        <sup class="newtext">NEW</sup>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="/sdfdsfsfsdfs/EstimatedCompositesdfdsfsfsdfs/Index">Estimated Composite sdfdsfsfsdfses 4th Qtr Election</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="/sdfdsfsfsdfs/sdfdsfsfsdfsdsFOF/Index">ds sfsdsdsd and Consent</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="/sdfdsfsfsdfs/NYIT2658Estimates/Index">NY IT-2658 Estimate</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="/sdfdsfsfsdfs/sdfdsfsfsdfsQuestionaire/Index">State sdfdsfsfsdfs Questionnaire</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="/sdfdsfsfsdfs/sdfdsfsfsdfsPrepSignUp/Index">sdfdsfsfsdfs Presdaaaation Sign-Up</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a class="mnn-nav-sub-click" data-id="ARCHIVES">
                                                            Archives
                                                            <i class="fa fa-down"></i>
                                                        </a>

                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled  ARCHIVES mnn-nav-ul-sub" style="display: none;">

                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/Communications/sdfdsfsfsdfs/sdfdsfsfsdfsForms/2018/Forms">2018 sdfdsfsfsdfs Forms</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2018/2018POFManual.pdf">2018 POF Manual</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2018/2018SampleForms965and965-A.PDF">2018 dfgdfgdg Manual addendum-Sample Forms 965 and 965-A</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/Commonfiles/2018/Section965StatebyStateInstructions.xlsx">Section 965 State by State Instructions</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/Communications/sdfdsfsfsdfs/sdfdsfsfsdfsForms/2017/Forms">2017 sdfdsfsfsdfs Forms</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2017/Sec965FAQ.pdf">Section 965 FAQs</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2017/2017dfgdfgdgManual.pdf">2017 dfgdfgdg Manual</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2017/2017sdfdsfsfsdfs_Information.pdf">2017 sdfdsfsfsdfs Information</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2017/2017dfgdfgdgManualAddendum965TransitionsdfdsfsfsdfsREVISED101218.pdf">2017 dfgdfgdg Manual Addendum 965 Transition sdfdsfsfsdfs revised 101218</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/Communications/sdfdsfsfsdfs/sdfdsfsfsdfsForms/2016/Forms">2016 sdfdsfsfsdfs Forms</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2016/2016_sdfdsfsfsdfsInformation.pdf">2016 sdfdsfsfsdfs Information</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2016/2016dfgdfgdgManual.pdf">2016 dfgdfgdg Manual</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/Communications/sdfdsfsfsdfs/sdfdsfsfsdfsForms/2015/Forms">2015 sdfdsfsfsdfs Forms</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2015/2015sdfdsfsfsdfsInformation.pdf">2015 sdfdsfsfsdfs Information</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2015/2015dfgdfgdgManual.pdf">2015 dfgdfgdg Manual</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/Communications/sdfdsfsfsdfs/sdfdsfsfsdfsForms/2014/Forms">2014 sdfdsfsfsdfs Forms</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2014/2014sdfdsfsfsdfsInformation.pdf">2014 sdfdsfsfsdfs Information</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2014/2014dfgdfgdgManual.pdf">2014 dfgdfgdg Manual</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/Communications/Forms">2013 sdfdsfsfsdfs Forms</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/CommonFiles/2013/2013sdfdsfsfsdfsInformation.pdf">2013 sdfdsfsfsdfs Information</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2013/2013dfgdfgdgManual.pdf">2013 dfgdfgdg Manual</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/Communications/Forms">2012 sdfdsfsfsdfs Forms</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/CommonFiles/2012/2012sdfdsfsfsdfsInformation.pdf">2012 sdfdsfsfsdfs Information</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2012/2012dfgdfgdgManual.pdf">2012 dfgdfgdg Manual</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="/Communications/Forms">2011 sdfdsfsfsdfs Forms</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/CommonFiles/2011/2011sdfdsfsfsdfsInformation.pdf">2011 sdfdsfsfsdfs Information</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/2011/2011dfgdfgdgManual.pdf">2011 dfgdfgdg Manual</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>

                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xl-3 float-left">
                                                <p data-id="FINPLANPTR" class="submenu-title mnn-sdaaaent-nav-click">
                                                   3
                                                    <i class="sub-up-down fa-up fa"></i>
                                                </p>

                                                <ul class="list-unstyled  FINPLANPTR ">

                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="/sdfdsfsfsdfs/FinPlanServices/Index">dfgdfgdg-dfgdgdfgdfg Planning Services sfsdsdsd</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xl-3 float-left">
                                                <p data-id="ADM" class="submenu-title mnn-sdaaaent-nav-click">
                                                    4
                                                    <i class="sub-up-down fa-up fa"></i>
                                                </p>

                                                <ul class="list-unstyled  ADM ">

                                                    <li>
                                                        <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/dfdfs/DirectAdmitBook.pdf">Direct dfdfs Manual</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/dfdfs/NewsdsdsdManual.pdf">New sdsdsd &amp; Principal Manual</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/dfdfs/sdsdsdshipagreements.pdf">sdsdsdship Agreements</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/dfdfs/Americas_Operating_Agreement_as_amended_July_4_2015.pdf">Americas Operating Agreement</a>


                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xl-3 float-left">
                                                <p data-id="RET" class="submenu-title mnn-sdaaaent-nav-click">
                                                    5
                                                    <i class="sub-up-down fa-up fa"></i>
                                                </p>

                                                <ul class="list-unstyled  RET ">

                                                    <li>
                                                        <a class="mnn-nav-sub-click" data-id="SPDS">
                                                            Summary Plan Descriptions (sdssdsd)
                                                            <i class="fa fa-down"></i>
                                                        </a>

                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled  sdssdsd mnn-nav-ul-sub" style="display: none;">

                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/sdsdaa/TYU sdsdsdship sdsdaa Plan - HR-10 Plan - 2016.pdf">TYU sdsdsdship sdsdaa Plan -HR10-Plan</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/sdsdaa/TYU sdsdaa Savings Plan -401(k) sdsdsd-principles - 2016.pdf">TYU sdsdaa Savings Plan-401(k)</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/sdsdaa/TYU PDBRP and IDBRP 2017.pdf">TYU PDBRP and IDBRP</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>

                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="/sdsdaa/401kContribution/_401kExclusionMsg">
                                                            401(k) asdaaa and
                                                            Election
                                                        </a>


                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a class="mnn-nav-sub-click" data-id="sdssdsd">
                                                            Summary Plan Descriptions (sdssdsd)
                                                            <i class="fa fa-down"></i>
                                                        </a>

                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled  sdssdsd mnn-nav-ul-sub" style="display: none;">

                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/sdsdaa/TYU sdsdsdship sdsdaa Plan - HR-10 Plan - 2016.pdf">TYU sdsdsdship sdsdaa Plan -HR10-Plan</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/sdsdaa/TYU sdsdaa Savings Plan -401(k) sdsdsd-principles - 2016.pdf">TYU sdsdaa Savings Plan-401(k)</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a target="_blank" href="/Commonfiles/sdsdaa/TYU PDBRP and IDBRP 2017.pdf">TYU asdadad and sdfsfsdsd</a>


                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>

                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xl-3 float-left">
                                                <a target="_blank" class="submenu-title mnn-sdaaaent-nav-click" href="https://sdaaa.TYU.net">6</a>


                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xl-3 float-left">
                                                <a class="submenu-title mnn-sdaaaent-nav-click" href="https://ptrshpdashboard.TYU.net">7</a>


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#navbarContent").hide();
        $('.navtrigger').click(function () {

            $("#navbarContent").toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');

            $("#mainListDiv").toggleClass("show_list");
            $("#mainListDiv").fadeIn();
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('body').addClass('loaded');

        }, 100);
    });

    $(".mnn-nav-ul-sub").hide();
    $(".mnn-nav-sub-click").click(function () {
        $(".mnn-nav-ul-sub").slideToggle();
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa fa-down fa fa-up');
        $(".mnn-nav-sub-click").sdaaaent().removeClass('navactive');
    });

    $(".ddn").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need to use flex properties to get this done. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @PraveenMP it's too general can you be more specific ?

Comment: use `<div class="row row-cols-4">` instead of `row d-block` and remove `float-left` near of `col-xl-3`

Comment: @xNoJustice not working . i have tried this one, and what is row-cols-4 ?

Comment: I get this [link](http://prntscr.com/tlqu15). You said "What I am looking for is to move sections 5 to below 1 st section and 6 one to below 2 nd section etc " If you want 5 section in one row, `div class="row row-cols-5">` and change your `col-xl-3` to `col`

Comment: @xNoJustice Please have a look into the question completely. I am looking to remove the space between rows(for some columns). and i need the sort order also in the same order . is not something just to change the sort order

Comment: @xNoJustice in the example which u shared , u can see the space between 1 and 5 th item and in other places also . That is what the main issue is

Comment: You can do with [bootstrap grids](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#nesting)

Comment: @xNoJustice Can u provide me a sample? I m not good in css. And the code which i shared is dynamically created one so i cannot change the structure only thing i can do is to change or add a class or style in the elements –

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps you [CSS: remove empty Space between boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013006/css-remove-empty-space-between-boxes/59013057#59013057)

In your case

```
.wrapper {
   column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 1.25rem;
}
.part {
   break-inside: avoid-column;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

.row will be .wrapper and .col-xl-3 is .part, I recommend you not to use bootstrap classes for this

Comment: We are supporting different devices , like mobile Ipad , ipad pro etc ..so getting out of bootstrap will introduce problems in other devices. Is there any work around for supporting different devices  with this solution ?

Comment: Yes of course, use media queries for that and control the colums with this property column-count: 3;

Comment: it is working with column-count changes in media query , but the issue is since this one is a dynamically created nav bar there are many sub levels also there . Just like a tree , so when i open those sub levels the items are changing or it is kind of changing its postion and sometimes its even arrange everything in two columns. Any idea about this ?

Comment: at least it should distribute the contents equally , Now i am not getting how its distributing the layout items, If I am opening a menu here it is kind of rearranging the navbar layout in some manner

Comment: Doy you mean inside the .part? items inside won´t be affected by the column-count, so I don´t know if I am understanding you can you share with me some image or URL to see what is happening?

Comment: sure give me a min . i can share you a fiddle link

Comment: you can have a look into this fiddle , this one is one is a demo i just created it for testing purpose http://jsfiddle.net/q2oe0b9x/ You can change the screen width to >1200 and try to open nav bar items to see the behaviour , in mobile devices and i pad there is no isses , since the column-count is 1 there issue is there in large devices